# Напечатать все n-значные нечетные натуральные числа в порядке убывания

Tags: python

```
Задание:  **Дано натуральное число n.
Напечатайте все n-значные нечетные натуральные числа в порядке убывания.**
```

[это ссылка на код](https://ideone.com/LkAySA)

[image: код]

как сделать чтобы переменная вычислялась только между двумя брейк поинтами???

[image: Другая прога(похожая, но интересуют брейк поинты!!!!!)]

а вот код собственно:

```
n = int(input("n="))
# создаем пустой список для хранения простых чисел
lst = []
# в k будем хранить количество делителей
k = 0
# пробегаем все числа от 2 до N
for i in range(2, n + 1 ):
    # пробегаем все числа от 2 до текущего
    for j in range(2, i):
        # ищем количество делителей
        if i % j == 0:
            k = k + 1
    # если делителей нет, добавляем число в список
    if k == 0:
        lst.append(i)
    else:
        k = 0
# выводим на экран список
print(lst)
```

Хочу, чтобы дебаггер только значения `lst.append(i)` показывал!!

Comment: Во-первых вставьте код в вопрос в виде текста, а не в виде скриншота (вставить, выделить, нажать кнопку `{}` в редакторе вопроса). Во-вторых у вас здесь не весь код - не видно откуда берется n. В-третьих, он у вас скорее всего вводится через `input()`, а `input` возвращает строку а не число. По сути вы пытаетесь к строке прибавить 1, на что и ругается интерпретатор.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо, но теперь вот, что:  https://prnt.sc/hm6gwq

Comment: Все дополнения к вопросу должны быть прямо в вопросе в виде текста, а не скриншотов. Для редактирования вопроса нажмите "править" под вопросом.

Comment: @insolor, понял, исправлю!!!(уже)

Comment: @Romer, уточните пожалуйста -  вам простые или нечетные числа нужны?

Comment: @MaxU, простые, а так же не понимаю, как с дебаггером управиться((((((вопрос в начале)

Comment: @Romer, вы что-то не то пытаетесь решить вашим кодом. В задании у вас нужно найти все n-значные нечетные числа, а в коде вы ищите простые числа до n. n-значные это количество знаков числа = n. Т.е. если у вас n=3, то нужно проверить все числа от 100 до 999 (а не от 1 до 3)